# How do I provide my own web service implementation instance?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I have a web service (JAX-RPC) that runs on application server (Websphere Application Server 7.0).
Normally the development process looks like this:

- I write a class with web service implementation (e.g. MyService.java)
- The IDE generates web service endpoint interface (e.g. MyService_SEI.java)
- The IDE generates configuration XMLs

When the web service is deployed, MyService_SEI is the declared service interface and the application server instantiates a MyService instance by means of the public no-arg constructor.

But what if I want to do constructor injection (i.e. have MyService class without a no-arg constructor) or if I want to provide a dynamic proxy object which implements MyService_SEI and use that?

Is there a way I can take control of the instantiation procedure (like a filter or interceptor) to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, error - deleted comment

Comment: only read concept but did you explore aspectj? maybe reword this as an aspect j question? but i think you need to trigger your aspectj only after container makes its object

Comment: I am not interested in any solutions that require me to make each WS function call something else. I already have that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do constructor injection as Injection always occur after the default constructor is called. If you try to use an injected reference inside the default constructor it will ALWAYS fail, there's no workaround for this as this is mandate by the specification.
So the first option you mentioned is discarded.

For the second option, using a filter or interceptor, you actually have an option. WebSphere WebServices are build using Axis2 implementation and Axis provide a way of [implementing Handlers](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html#Handlers).

You can add handlers into the JAX-WS runtime environment to perform additional processing of request and response messages.

Here's a handler example, from Axis documentation:

```
package org.apache.samples.handlersample;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class SampleProtocolHandler implements
       javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

   public void close(MessageContext messagecontext) {
   }

   public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
       return null;
   }

   public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messagecontext) {
       return true;
   }

   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messagecontext) {
       Boolean outbound = (Boolean) messagecontext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
       if (outbound) {
           // Include your steps for the outbound flow.
       }
       return true;
   }

}
```

And than you add a handler.xml file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <jws:handler-chain name="MyHandlerChain">
            <jws:protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP ##ANOTHER_BINDING</jws:protocol-bindings>
            <jws:port-name-pattern 
             xmlns:ns1="http://handlersample.samples.apache.org/">ns1:MySampl*</jws:port-name-pattern>
       <jws:service-name-pattern 
             xmlns:ns1="http://handlersample.samples.apache.org/">ns1:*</jws:service-name-pattern>
            <jws:handler>
                    <jws:handler-class>org.apache.samples.handlersample.SampleLogicalHandler</jws:handler-class>
            </jws:handler>
            <jws:handler>
                    <jws:handler-class>org.apache.samples.handlersample.SampleProtocolHandler2</jws:handler-class>
            </jws:handler>
            <jws:handler>
                    <jws:handler-class>org.apache.samples.handlersample.SampleLogicalHandler</jws:handler-class>
            </jws:handler>
            <jws:handler>
                    <jws:handler-class>org.apache.samples.handlersample.SampleProtocolHandler2</jws:handler-class>
            </jws:handler>
    </jws:handler-chain>
```

Comment: I am aware of handlers, which are extremely lackluster. They allow you to perform operations on SOAP headers and parts, which is not what i'm looking for. I am looking for the ability to use a dynamic proxy object implementing the endpoint interface.

Answer (score 1):

an easy method would be to make two classes. one your class with all the bells and whistles (constructor injection etc lets call it worker). and the actual service. the service would delegate what it needs to the worker class, who it can get by calling some factory method.

The factory can even look at some common db or other config to decide which run time instance (which class, what config, shared or common) so you have good separation and power

Just cause you are using one framework/ method of injection does not mean you cannot mix to make it more powerful

Comment: I have this setup already. My Web Service implementation class just calls the dynamic proxy in every function. What I want is to cut out the middle man and eliminate this delegate class.

Comment: i think this would be a good suggestion for a new feature. to tell containers to call some specific method on some object passing the object they have created to allow us to inject in to it. On the other hand the middle man can be just seen as good design/ dividing up the work

Comment: So a class with 30 methods like this:

`    public String getPhysicalAddress(String location) throws Exception{
        return ws.getPhysicalAddress(location);
    }`

That's good design?

Comment: its verbose and a pain and a lot of repetition. do not see any elegant way out of it. if you don't mind forget about object injection from an external framework spring etc you could just do the changes in your own class behavior/ data depending on some other meta data. but then would have more ifs. so like i said maybe you need to start a Java change for WS and other container managed beans? did you see the spring API is there anything WS specific?

Comment: not sure if spring already has what you need but worth a look http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html ; 2 ] http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/what-is-spring-ws.html and 3 ] http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html